# ORDER on mdx query is not working

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm having a problem to order a column with a MDX query.

this is my query:

```
with
     Member
     [Measures].[MemberUN] as '[Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.UNIQUE_NAME'
     member
     [Measures].[Memberlevel] as '[Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.LEVEL.ordinal'
Select
ORDER([Employee].[Employee Department].allmembers,[Measures].[Memberlevel]) on 1,
{[Measures].[MemberUN],[measures].[MemberLevel]} on 0
From [Adventure Works]
```

For some reason it's not ordering the table with the level ordinal.

Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setting for sorting of MDX does not break the level hierarchy, i. e. it keeps the main order of first the parent, then its children. It only applies the sorting to the children of the same parent. If you want to break the hierarchy in your sorting, use `BASC` ("breaking sort ascending") instead of the default setting `ASC`, or use `BDESC` instead of `DESC`. The following query sorts in the way that you probably intended:

```
with
     Member
     [Measures].[MemberUN] as '[Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.UNIQUE_NAME'
     member
     [Measures].[Memberlevel] as '[Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.LEVEL.ordinal'
Select
ORDER([Employee].[Employee Department].allmembers, [Measures].[Memberlevel], BASC) on 1,
{[Measures].[MemberUN],[measures].[MemberLevel]} on 0
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Thanks! I come up with something similar but I uses the DrillDownLevel in the ORDER. Your way is better! thanks!